# Mac ports installation of gcc46 failing due to architecture problems

Tags: macos, macports

When trying to install `gcc46` on OS X 10.6.4 using `port` (MacPorts 1.9.1) i get the following errors:

```
artemis:foo$ sudo port install gcc46
Error: Cannot install gcc46 for the arch(s) 'x86_64' because
Error: its dependency gmp is only installed for the arch 'i386'
Error: and the configured universal_archs 'ppc i386' are not sufficient.
Error: Unable to execute port: architecture mismatch
```

MacPorts was freshly installed on the 10.6 system.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this or how to install gcc46 for i386?

*(Previously asked and as of now unanswered on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/176561/mac-ports-installation-of-gcc46-failing-due-to-architecture-problems).)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason the `universal_archs` configurations was wrong. An answer on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/176561/mac-ports-installation-of-gcc46-failing-due-to-architecture-problems/178724#178724) now worked:

- in `/opt/local/etc/macports/` copy `macports.conf.default` to `macports.conf`
- make sure `universal_archs` in it is set to `x86_64 i386`
- now go for clean installs, e.g. by following the [migration instructions](http://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration)

Answer (score 0):

Try installing first gmp only with the `universal` variant :

> sudo port install gmp +universal

Then reinstall gcc46.

Comment: That didn't do it, same error as before.